# isPreviewing prop not updating in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

Hi am building an article editor. I have an issue where the isPreviewing prop of the Elementviewer component does not get updated when the state of TextEditor changes. Can you help me figure out why this is, I've done some debugging and asked chatgpt and I can't seem to find a solution.

My TextEditor.js file

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';

import ElementViewer from '../tagViewer/elementViewer';

function TextEditor(props) {
  //state holders and reactdom root


  const [root, setRoot] = useState(null);
  const [elementViewers, setElementViewers] = useState([]);
  const [contentHolderArray, setContentHolderArray] = useState([]);
  const [dataCalls, setDataCalls] = useState(0);
  const [isPreviewing, setUpisPreviewing] = useState(false);
  const [previewButtonClicked, setPreviewButtonClicked] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    setRoot(ReactDOMClient.createRoot(document.getElementById('rendered-element-holder')));
  }, []);

  // This function will render a new element when the Add element button clicked

  const renderNewElement = () => {
    
    setElementViewers(prevElementViewers => [
      ...prevElementViewers,
      <ElementViewer key={prevElementViewers.length} id={generateRandomId()} index={prevElementViewers.length} onDismount={handleDismount} sendForPreview={handleElementData} isPreviewing={previewButtonClicked}/>

    ])
    
  };


  //This function randomly generates an id for the Elementviewer components

  function generateRandomId(length = 11) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let result = '';
  
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
  
    return result;
  }
  



  //This function will remove the dismounted component from the elementViewers state
  
  const handleDismount = (data) => {
    setElementViewers((prevElementViewers) => prevElementViewers.filter(
      elementComponent => elementComponent.props.id !== data.componentId
    )
    );
  };


  // This function changes the state of isPreview to true

  const clickToStartPreview = () => {
    setUpisPreviewing(true);
    setPreviewButtonClicked(true);
    console.log("previewButton has been clicked");
    console.log(previewButtonClicked);
    
  }
  // This function will handle all of the data from the tags and bundle them into a nested array

  const handleElementData = (data) => {
    console.log("handleElementData function has been called");
    const contentCopyArray = [...contentHolderArray];
    contentCopyArray.push(data);
    setContentHolderArray(contentCopyArray);
    setDataCalls(dataCalls => dataCalls + 1);
    console.log("check THE number of datacalls", dataCalls);
  }

  
  //this function is used by the sort function in the useEffect hook to sort the array

  const compareIndexes = (index1, index2) => {
    return index1[0] - index2[0];
  }

  //This function is used after all of the handleDataCalls and will send preview data back to LightRoomAdmin

  const afterAllDataCalls = () => {
    console.log("This is after all of the data calls");
    console.log(contentHolderArray);
    props.getPreview(contentHolderArray);
  }
  /* This useEffect hook will sort all of the arrays based on index lowest to highest,
  it will resolve when all of the calls are done */

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Check for useEffect hook that calculates the number of dataCalls and if previewButton has been clicked");
    console.log(dataCalls);
    console.log(previewButtonClicked);
    if(dataCalls === elementViewers.length && previewButtonClicked === true){
      const copyContentArray = [...contentHolderArray];
      copyContentArray.sort(compareIndexes);
      setContentHolderArray(copyContentArray);
      afterAllDataCalls();
    }

  }, [dataCalls, elementViewers, previewButtonClicked]);

  /* This useEffecthook tests to see whether dataCalls are getting called 
  Delete after testing*/

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Datacalls", dataCalls);
  }, [dataCalls]);


  

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="rendered-element-holder">
        {elementViewers.map(ElementViewer => ElementViewer)}
      </div>
      <button className="add-element" onClick={renderNewElement}>
        Add element
      </button>
      <button className="preview-article" onClick={clickToStartPreview}>Preview article</button>
      <button className="post-article">Post article</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextEditor;

My ElementVier.js file

import {React, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import HComponent from "./individualTags/h1Component/h1Component";

import PComponent from "./individualTags/pComponent/pComponent";
import ImageComponent from "./individualTags/imageComponent/imageComponent";
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import ElementCSS from "./elementViewer.js";



function ElementViewer(props){
    // This component is a tag that lets you view a tag with it's type and its first 30 characters.
    
    // states of Tagviewer

    const [tag, setTag] = useState("");
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState("");
    const [content, setContent] = useState("");
    const [originalElementID, setOriginalElementID] = useState("");
    const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(false);
    const [sendDataToParent, setSendDataToParent] = useState(props.isPreviewing);
    const [elementIndex, setElementIndex] = useState(props.index);
    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(true);
    const [id,setId] = useState(props.id);
    const [selectedComponent, setSelectedComponent] = useState(null);
    
    
    
    // this is a hook that set up react root

    

    const handleData = (data) => {
        console.log("data arrived to ElementViewer");
        setTag(data.tag);
        setContent(data.content);

        if(data.tag !== "image"){
            if(data.content.length > 30){
                setPreview(data.content.slice(0, 30) + "...");
            } else {
                setPreview(data.content);
            }
        }
        setIsPreview(true);
    }

    // This function updates the state from the child component
    const handleDelete = (data) => {
        console.log("handleDelete in elementViewer has been called");
        console.log(data.willDelete);
        if(data.willDelete === true){
            setIsMounted(false);
        }
    }

    // This useEffect hook passes the delete setIsMounted state and it's key to the parent TextEditor component

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isMounted === false){
            const dismountData = {
                componentIsMounted: false,
                componentId: id
            };
            props.onDismount(dismountData);
        }
    }, [isMounted])
    



    // This function will write the content into the tag

    const turnElementIntoJSX = () => {
        const elementJSX = `<${tag}>${content}</${tag}>`;
        console.log(elementJSX);
    }

    // This function will give the users different form based on which tag they chose


    
    const assignFormComponent =  (event) => {
    const selectedTag = event.target.value;
    console.log(selectedTag);
    let component = null;
     setTag(selectedTag);
    console.log(tag);
    

    switch (selectedTag) {
        case "h1":
        component = (
            <HComponent
            getTag={selectedTag}
            getContent={content}
            getId={originalElementID}
            handleData={handleData}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            />
        );
        break;
        case "h2":
        component = (
            <HComponent
            getTag={selectedTag}
            getContent={content}
            getId={originalElementID}
            handleData={handleData}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            />
        );
        break;
        case "h3":
        component = (
            <HComponent
            getTag={selectedTag}
            getContent={content}
            getId={originalElementID}
            handleData={handleData}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            />
        );
        break;
        case "h4":
        component = (
            <HComponent
            getTag={selectedTag}
            getContent={content}
            getId={originalElementID}
            handleData={handleData}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            />
        );
        break;
        case "p":
        component = (
            <PComponent
            getTag={selectedTag}
            getContent={content}
            getId={originalElementID}
            handleData={handleData}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            />
        );
        break;
        case "img":
        component = (
            <ImageComponent
            getTag={selectedTag}
            getContent={content}
            getId={originalElementID}
            handleData={handleData}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            />
        );
        break;
        default:
        console.log("Image didn't load, something went wrong");
    }

    setSelectedComponent(component);
    };

    





    ///This function will remove the preview state and allow you to edit

    const editElement =  () => {
        const tagHolder = document.getElementById("tag-preview");
        
        const tagValue = tagHolder.textContent;
        setIsPreview(false);

        
        
        console.log(content);
        let component = null;
        
    
        switch (tagValue) {
            case "h1":
            component = (
                <HComponent
                getTag={tagValue}
                getContent={content}
                getId={originalElementID}
                handleData={handleData}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                />
            );
            break;
            case "h2":
            component = (
                <HComponent
                getTag={tagValue}
                getContent={content}
                getId={originalElementID}
                handleData={handleData}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                />
            );
            break;
            case "h3":
            component = (
                <HComponent
                getTag={tagValue}
                getContent={content}
                getId={originalElementID}
                handleData={handleData}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                />
            );
            break;
            case "h4":
            component = (
                <HComponent
                getTag={tagValue}
                getContent={content}
                getId={originalElementID}
                handleData={handleData}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                />
            );
            break;
            case "p":
            component = (
                <PComponent
                getTag={tagValue}
                getContent={content}
                getId={originalElementID}
                handleData={handleData}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                />
            );
            break;
            case "img":
            component = (
                <ImageComponent
                getTag={tagValue}
                getContent={content}
                getId={originalElementID}
                handleData={handleData}
                handleDelete={handleDelete}
                />
            );
            break;
            default:
            console.log("Image didn't load, something went wrong");
        }
        
        setSelectedComponent(component);
        };
        
    // This useEffect hook updates the sendDataToParent state when the props.isPreviewing gets updated    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("updating is previewing prop");
        setSendDataToParent(props.isPreviewing);
    }, [props.isPreviewing]);



    

    // This function will send the id, tag, and component back to the textEditor parent component. It will be called from
    // TextEditor using a ref

    const sendDataToTextEditor = () => {
        if (props.isPreviewing) {
            const dataArray = [elementIndex, tag, content];
            props.sendForPreview(dataArray);
            console.log("sending data to the text editor");
        }
    }

    // This useEffectHook send information to the parentComponent when the sendDataToParent state is true, 

    useEffect(() => {
        sendDataToTextEditor();
    }, [props.isPreviewing]);

    


    if(isMounted){    
        if(isPreview === true){
            return (
            <div className="viewer-holder">
                <div className="viewer-holder-tag">
                    <h3 id="tag-preview">{tag}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="viewer-holder-preview">
                    <p>{preview}</p>
                </div>
                <button onClick={editElement}>Edit</button>
            </div>
        )
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="creator-holder">
                    <form>
                        <label htmlFor="tag-selector">tag</label>
                        <select id="tag-selector" onChange={assignFormComponent} defaultValue={tag}>
                            <option>Select the desired tag</option>
                            <option>h1</option>
                            <option>h2</option>
                            <option>h3</option>
                            <option>h4</option>
                            <option>p</option>
                            <option>img</option>
                            


                        </select>
                    </form>
                    <div id="rendered-component-holder">{selectedComponent}</div>
                    <button onClick={turnElementIntoJSX}>Test for jsx</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}   

export default ElementViewer;
```